# NameError: undefined local variable or method 'v' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, local, nameerror

Just installed and was planning on starting Ruby today, and was running through a few test lines of code to make sure everything was installed properly.  Simple math and puts commands work fine, but when I was trying to print which version I was using I received this error.

The code I typed, along with the ensuing code and error message I got was:

```
 PS C:\Users\Luke> irb
 irb(main):001:0> ruby -v
 NameError: undefined local variable or method 'v' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
 irb(main):002:0>
```

Out of the four similar questions I found here on stackoverflow, and the handful from google, there were quite a few NameErrors but nothing that used "ruby -v" as the input, and I'm not skilled enough yet to glean anything useful from the answers I found.

I'm using Windows 10, and Ruby version 2.0.0-p647.

I'm pretty stumped here.  Should I have done something with my path variables?  That's usually the first thing I check but the installer had a checkbox to "add Ruby executables to your PATH," so I assumed this took care of it.  When I checked the environment variable it hadn't changed and was still the Windows default, but wouldn't the most basic Ruby commands not work in the terminal if the PATH wasn't set up properly?

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: `ruby -v` is to be run from the command prompt in a terminal session, not within IRB. My [favorite Fonzie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQkntcq0jBI).

Comment: Got it, thanks so much! And thanks for the Fonzie clip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ruby -v` won't work inside `irb`

You need to enter `RUBY_VERSION`

Comment: Oh I see, so RUBY_VERSION if I'm in the irb, ruby -v if it's just a terminal session.  Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Getting Ruby Version Information Inside an Interactive Session

### Get Output from Command-Line Flags in REPL

Use backticks to capture the output of a shell command in a REPL like irb or pry. For example:

```
`ruby -v`
#=> "ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]\n"
```

### Get Data from Ruby Constants

The data you want is also stored in various Ruby constants. For example:

```
[RUBY_VERSION, RUBY_PATCHLEVEL, RUBY_RELEASE_DATE, RUBY_REVISION, RUBY_PLATFORM]
#=> ["2.2.3", 173, "2015-08-18", 51636, "x86_64-darwin14"]
```

### Constructing an Equivalent String from Constants

You can put the value of the constants into a string that matches the output of the interpreter's `-v` flag, but you'll have to construct the string yourself. For example:

```
sprintf "ruby %sp%s (%s revision %s) [%s]\n",
  RUBY_VERSION, RUBY_PATCHLEVEL, RUBY_RELEASE_DATE, RUBY_REVISION, RUBY_PLATFORM
#=> "ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]\n"
```